# Is there something like an enumeration that contains all MouseEvent-Types?

Tags: javascript

I want to use `addEventListener(type, listenerFunction)` to add the same listenerFunction for all  types of MouseEvents. I could do this by adding them all manually,

```
addEventListener('clicked', listener);
addEventListener('mouseOver', listener);
...
```

but it would be more elegant to do this in a loop that iterates over all types, like

```
for (var i = 0; i < EventTypeList.length; i++) {
    addEventListener(EventTypeList[i], listener);
}
```

Is there a List with constants for the names of event-types? I didn't find something like that on the net yet.

Comment: There is no such built-in list. You can define it yourself and iterate it in loop.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to give jQuery a try to help you with this.  While it can be done in standard javascript, jQuery packages all in nice and easy to use features.

In jQuery it would look something like this

```
 $(".listenForMouse").bind("click dblclick hover", function(event) {

 });
```

A listing of the different mouse events can be found at http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in list for mouse events, but there is a [solid list of events on MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events). There are three things you could do:

1. You could write a function to iterate over an array of these events
2. You could use jQuery like what Mr. Bob Tate suggests
3. You could extend the `addEventListener` function to do something a bit like the first option like this:

   `EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = (function(_super) {
     return function (events, callback) {
       if (typeof events === "string") {
         _super.call(this, events, callback);
       } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call( arguments[0] ) === '[object Array]') {
         for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
           _super.call(this, events[i], callback);
         }
       }
     }
   })(EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener);`

That way you could do something like this:

```
var mouseEvents =
    ['click',
     'mouseenter',
     'mousedown',
     'mouseleave',
     'mousedown',
     'mousemove',
     'mouseout',
     'mouseover',
     'mouseout',
     'mouseup',
     'show',
     'contextmenu',
     'dblclick'];

someElement.addEventListener(mouseEvents, function () {
  display.textContent = "mouse events: " + ++eventCounter;
})
```

[**Here's a pen**](http://codepen.io/argo49/pen/LsJFC) if you want to mess around with it.